# Implement Thomas J Bradley's Signature Pad Ruby on Rails Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, signaturepad

I'm not very good at rails yet, and I'm trying to collect a user's signature at the end of a form. I've got the form showing up in my view just fine now, but I don't really know where to start to get it converted into an image.

On the documentation for Signature Pad it suggests using this code:

```
instructions = JSON.load(data).map { |h| "line #{h['mx']},#{h['my']} #{h['lx']},#{h['ly']}" } * ' '
system "convert -size 198x55 xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw '#{instructions}' signature.png"
```

but it doesn't have any documentation on where/how to use it.

Do I put this in my create function?
How would I get it working with the carrierwave uploader gem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to work through this.  Here's what I did.

In the controller create method I added this code before @model.save

```
instructions = JSON.parse(params[:output]).map { |h| "line #{h['mx'].to_i},#{h['my'].to_i} #{h['lx'].to_i},#{h['ly'].to_i}" } * ' '
tempfile = Tempfile.new(["signature", '.png'])
Open3.popen3("convert -size 600x100 xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw @- #{tempfile.path}") do |input, output, error|
  input.puts instructions
end
@yourmodel.signature = tempfile
```

For this to work of course you have to have a Carrierwave gem installed, then set up an uploader like this.
In Terminal:

```
rails generate uploader Signature
```

In the model you're uploading to:

```
mount_uploader :signature, SignatureUploader
```

Hope that helps someone with the same issue.

Comment: Hello, this is very useful, can you tell me where did you get que params[:output] ?